# dynamically changing CSS background-image

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm fairly new to both PHP and Javascript, so please forgive my ignorance and poor use of terminology, but I'll do my best to explain exactly what I'm struggling to achieve.

I have information stored in a PHP array that I call to my index page using the function below (the code below is in a separate PHP file called articles.php that's included in my index.php) :

```
<?php

function get_news_feed($article_id, $article) {

  $output = "";

  $output .= '<article class="img-wrapper">';
  $output .= '<a href="article.php?id=' . $article_id . '">';
  $output .= '<div class="news-heading">';
  $output .= "<h1>";
  $output .= $article["title"];
  $output .= "</h1>";
  $output .= "<p>";
  $output .= "Read more...";
  $output .= "</p>";
  $output .= "</div>";
  $output .= '<div id="news-img-1">';
  $output .= "</div>";
  $output .= "</a>";
  $output .= "</article>";

  return $output;
} 

$articles = array();
$articles[] = array(
  "title" => "Andy at NABA",
  "description" => "Docendi, est quot probo erroribus id.",
  "img" => "img/gym-01.jpg",
  "date" => "05/04/2013" 
);
$articles[] = array(
  "title" => "Grand Opening",
  "description" => "Docendi, est quot probo erroribus id.",
  "img" => "img/gym-01.jpg",
  "date" => "05/04/2013" 
);

?>
```

My index.php looks like the following minus some HTML that plays no role in this process:

```
<?php 
include("inc/articles.php");
?>

<?php
$pageTitle = "Home";
include("inc/header.php"); 
?>

<section class="col-4 news">

    <?php

    $total_articles = count($articles);
    $position = 0;
    $news_feed = "";

    foreach($articles as $article_id => $article) {

    $position = $position + 1;
        if ($total_articles - $position < 2) {
            $news_feed .= get_news_feed($article_id, $article);
        }
    } 

    echo $news_feed;

    ?>

</section>
```

I am aiming to dynamically change the CSS Background-Image property of the div element with ID **news-img-1** using Javascript.

I have tried such things as:

```
document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url('<?php $article["img"]; ?>')';

document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url('http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/' + '<?php $article["img"]; ?>')';

document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url('window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + '<?php $article["img"]; ?>')';
```

.....but I'm getting nowhere!! My code in practise works because the following Javascript inserts an image correctly:

```
document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url("img/gym-01.jpg")';
```

[Here is my site up and running](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/), the images should be placed in the empty circles you'll see! Any help would be great, this ones tough for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comparing the hard coded javascript to ones that don't work, I notice that you are not including the double-quotes around the `<?php $article["img"]; ?>` snippet. The hard coded one shows

```
= 'url("img/gym-01.jpg")'
```

but the ones with the php snippet will produce

```
 = 'url(img/gym-01.jpg)'
```

so perhaps if you modify it to

```
document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url("'<?php $article["img"]; ?>'")';
```

OR

edit the `get_news_feed` function as follows:

replace these lines

```
$output .= '<div id="news-img-1">';
$output .= "</div>";
```

with

```
$output .= '<div class="news-img"><img src="' . $article["img"] . '"></div>' ;
```

and change your css like so:

```
article.img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

div.news-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

OR

Modify your get_news_feed function, change the statement for the `<div id="news-img-1">` output to include a data-url attribute like:

```
$output .= '<div class="news-img" data-url="' . $article["img"] . '">';
```

Then add a jquery statement like:

```
$(".news-img").each( function() { 
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data("url") +")" ); 
    });
```

The jquery statement goes in a static js file as opposed to generating the script in php.

Comment: Cheer for the help Dom, but still no success... I also tried document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + <?php $article["img"]; ?> + '")'; to incorporate Mohammad's input

Comment: I've done a fair bit of research to try work this out myself, but I've come up short, I really thought it would be an easy one...

Comment: looking at the script on your site, the first commented out line looks almost right, except for the extraneous single quotes scattered about. in the part that says 'url('http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/img/gym-01.jpg' + '')'; , the second single quote should be a double quote, and the ' + ''); at the end needs to be "); ... I think your problem is just structuring your php to output the right syntax

Comment: perhaps doing `<?php $url = $article["img"]; echo '\'url(\"$url\")\'' ; ?>` would do it.

Comment: I'll try these when I get back to my computer, cheers Dom. It's just dawned on me that for this to work correctly, the code needs to be integrated into my PHP function so it's included during each loop when I'm calling the function/array??

Comment: I think I'd modify your `get_news_feed` function and change the output for the `<div id="news-img-1">` output to include a data-url attribute ... like ... `$output .= '<div class="news-img" data-url="' + $article["img"] + '">';` and then add a jquery statement like `$(".news-img").each( function() { $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data("url") +")" ); } );` ... the jquery statement goes in a static js file as opposed to generating the script in php

Comment: If you're not comfortable in jQuery, you could simply output a normal img tag inside your news-img divs rather than using the background-image css property, then use css to set the z-index on the div to -1000 ( or some other negative number ) to place it behind the other content. I'll edit the answer to illustrate

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, I'll try both methods when I get back. I originally would of used an img tag as it worked on something similar I produced, but using the circular divs with an img tag was a nightmare when I made the site fully responsive. I'll give it another look though. The JQuery option looks promising

Comment: you my friend, are a genius!!!! the JQuery technique works like a treat! and I've learnt something new, which is the main thing. I've edited the answer to include your 3rd option, hope that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes from your PHP tags and see if it works!

Do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('news-img-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + <?php $article["img"]; ?> + ')';
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: Thank you for your input Mohammad,. I'm getting no JS console error, but the images are still not displayed with your idea. to me Logic would suggest it should work :) but I'm guessing there's an issue with PHP being server side?

Comment: I have also tried to include the public file path in my PHP array -  "img" => "http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/img/gym-01.jpg" but still no joy